# Text between hyphen block

Tags: regex

I have some strings in the following format:

```
Foo - Foo Bar - Test Test - Foo
Test - Foo - Bar - Foo
```

I'd like to retrieve all text between the second and third occurrence of `-`, including the first hyphen and the space in front of the second hyphen, but not the second hyphen itself.

For the two examples, it would match following (I have replaced spaces with `_` for clarification):

```
-_Test_Test_
-_Bar_
```

Comment: @rock321987 I have tried `^(?:[^-]*-){2}([^-]*)` but it does not include the first hyphen

Comment: language you are using?

Comment: Use [`^[^-]+-[^-]+(-[^-]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/hA5wT3/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^[^-]*-[^-]*(-[^-]*)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/xY5aH2/1)**

**NOTE** :- *Match is in first capturing group*